# golang http GET request but blocked by Cloudflare CAPTCHA

Tags: go, web-scraping, header, httprequest, captcha

First, Sorry for my poor english. I am not good at english enough.
I am making web scraper with golang, with http and goquery package.
I sent the GET request But blocked by captcha.
after I googled it and add Header user-agent with "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36",
but also blocked by captcha.
but when I coded with python, it works very well
I coudn't know why this happens.
here is the functions in my go code

```
func GetCharacterList() {
    url := "https://namu.wiki/"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    checkErr(err)

    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36")
    req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "*/*")
    req.Header.Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
    fmt.Println(req.Header.Values("accept-encoding"))
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    checkErr(err)
    reader, _ := gzip.NewReader(resp.Body)
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(reader)
    checkErr(err)
    fmt.Println(doc.Text())
    resp.Body.Close()
}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

and this is my python code

```
import requests

request_headers = { 
'User-Agent' : ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36'), } 
request = requests.get("https://namu.wiki/",headers=request_headers)
print(request.text)
```

I searched about this problem so many time but coudn't find working solutions.
There were just some packages 2 or 3 years ago that doesn't work nowadays 
If solutions I want was already exists, I'm so sorry.
but I really don't know about difference between python's request and golang's request,
and also tried to know difference and added more some headers but didn't work well, just show cloudflare captcha

Comment: The blocking is not only related to http headers but ip and how often you access the resource. The heuristic is private. My advice is : try to use a proxy